# get nested json value by index - flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am able to get values from a json file using flutter but since the json data is nested i want to be able to get the first parent and its nested value using an integer number
[my json data here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BrightCode1/ohms-json/master/categories.json)

**main.dat**

```
 List<JsonModel> myModel = [];
 List<CatSubcategory> subCate = [];

loadData() async {
    var res = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      String resBody = res.body;
      var jsonDecode = json.decode(resBody);
      for (var data in jsonDecode) {
        data['cat_subcategory'].map((x) {  
          return subCate.add(
              CatSubcategory(subName: x['sub_name'], subImage: x['sub_image']));
        }).toList();  
        myModel.add(JsonModel(
            category: data['category'],
            catId: data['cat_id'],
            catIcon: data['cat_icon'],
            catSubcategory: subCate));
        setState(() {});
      }


      int localInt = 0;
      for(var index = 0; index < myModel[localInt].catSubcategory.length; index++) {
        print(myModel[localInt].catSubcategory[index].subName);
      }


    } else {
      print("Something went wrong!");
    }

  }
```

instead of giving me the children of the first one which is `"category": "Design & Creativity",`, it will give me all of it from 0 - 3. so please how do i do this

If you require more explanation please let me know

Comment: Not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but you are mapping over every nested object inside your one json object, so it is no surprise you get more than one result?
also, this question is pure json / javascript, not flutter/dart

Comment: @Leviathan well am using flutter dart for this

Comment: @Brightcode sorry not understand what you want exactly

Comment: @Shubham OK so what I want is that in my json list there are 4 like list inside it which has a category of design, legal, and 2 others and what I want is to get the Nester value of the first one which is `cat_subcategory` by printing it out `myModel[localInt].catSubcategory[index].subName` and localInt is an integer which is 0. So how do I do it

Comment: Okay so means you want to get  `subName`, right?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede yeah in a list but I already know how to get it,  what I want now is to get only one of it eg I have Ads,  Ads0,  Ads1,  Ads2. And I want to get the one of Ads with others which is at 0 index

Comment: @Brightcode im getting this data this is right for you http://prntscr.com/xrf3c1

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede yeah exactly

Answer (score 1):

> First Answer

I hope this will work for you

```
  for(int index = 0; index < myModel[0].catSubcategory.length; index++) {
    print("==============>>${myModel[0].catSubcategory[index].subName}");
  }
```

> Second Answer

First, you need to initialize your `localInt` outside of your `loadData()` method. And set it value 0 in your `initState()`

```
  @override
  void initState() { 
    loadData(localInt);
    localInt = 0;
    super.initState();
  }

  int localInt;

  loadData(int data) async {
    ....

    for(int index = 0; index < myModel[data].catSubcategory.length; index++) {
        print("==============>>${myModel[data].catSubcategory[index].subName}");
    }

    ...
  }
```

Comment: I tried that and it works but why am using `int localInt = 0;` is so that I can change it when I click a button or use a dropdownbutton so it can change from 0 to 1 or 2 and get different children value

Comment: @Brightcode Ok means you are saying that when you used `int localInt = 0;` then it not work and in future you want to change this value on any clicks

Comment: Yeah that's what am looking for

Comment: @Brightcode I updated my answer you can check now

Comment: OK I will try it

Comment: still showing all `Ads, Ads0, Ads1, Ads2`